# Como manter valor no html5 mesmo alterando no modo F12?

Tags: javascript, html5

Segue o código:

**Html5:**

```
<button id="btnSave" data-id="1">Save Click</button>
```

**JS:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnSave").click(function(e) {
      AlertSave($(this).data("id"));
    });
  });

  function AlertSave(a) {
    alert(a);
  }
```

Se preferir em jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/5316/

Eu quero manter o valor `data-id` para que não seja alterado no modo `f12` (inspetor de elementos).

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Você pode tentar dificultar o acesso a ferramentas de debugação do navegador, mas bloquear definitivamente, não ha.

Comment: Suponha que o hacker não consiga alterar o valor no modo F12, mas ele altere a requisição em trânsito, usando alguma regra de firewall que ele configurou especificamente para tapear o seu site. Tem como resolver isso, também? Me parece que você quer que o computador do cliente, rodando código completamente desconhecido por você, totalmente fora do seu controle, garanta a segurança da sua aplicação. Isso é simplesmente impossível.

Comment: Se está no front-end, será possível ser alterado :/

Comment: @LucasCosta, entendi, obrigado por responder

Comment: @Ivella, o mais seguro é pelo database ? Tipo, fazer select e verificar se existe esse valor ...

Comment: A partir do momento que a informação é transitada pro lado do cliente, novamente, o máximo que você pode fazer é dificultar o acesso, bloquear modificação dele é impossível. Se quiser validar qualquer coisa, a melhor maneira é no lado do servidor

Comment: @MatheusMiranda eu não sei o que você tá tentando fazer, mas verificar se o valor existe no banco de dados não parece, a princípio, uma boa ideia. Um atacante poderia usar isso para tentar determinar, na tentativa e erro, o conteúdo do seu banco de dados, por exemplo. Mas não dá para responder sem entender melhor o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impedir o dado de ser alterado não tem como. Pode ser que nem seja um navegador que acesse seu site, pode ser um bot, pode ser um script em alguma linguagem de programação criado para simular ser um navegador, mas que ignore completamente o JavaScript, e cujo o propósito seja tapear o seu site. Em suma, você não pode ter absolutamente nenhuma ilusão de controle sobre o que acontece do outro lado do cabo de rede.

Se você quiser guardar um valor numa página, e quiser que esse valor seja enviado de volta sem alteração, você precisa assinar digitalmente esse valor no servidor, guardá-lo com a assinatura na página, e quando receber o valor de volta no servidor, verificar a assinatura digital para determinar se foi ou não alterado. Dessa maneira você não consegue impedir que o valor seja alterado, mas tem a garantia (do algoritmo de assinatura digital) que você vai descobrir caso o dado tenha sido alterado.

Essa é uma das maneiras que o framework web [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) usa para gravar cookies de maneira segura.